# Как объединить коллекцию элементов c одинаковым id?

Tags: kotlin, group-by

Есть коллекция объектов:

```kotlin
data class VideoStatistic(val id: String, val viewingTime: Long)
```

В эту коллекцию может попасть несколько видео с одинаковыми id, но разным временем просмотра. Например, `VideoStatistic(1, 2)` и `VideoStatistic(1, 3)`.

Как мне объединить такие элементы, чтобы в результате получить коллекцию, в которой будет лежать `VideoStatistic(1, 5)`?

Answer (score 0):

Предположим, у вас есть коллекция объектов:

```
val statistics: Collection<VideoStatistic> =
    listOf(
        VideoStatistic("1", 2),
        VideoStatistic("1", 3),
        VideoStatistic("2", 2),
    )
```

С помощью стандартной функции [`groupBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/group-by.html) это можно сделать следующим образом:

```
val mergedStatistics: Collection<VideoStatistic> =
    statistics.groupBy(VideoStatistic::id, VideoStatistic::viewingTime)
        .mapValues { (id, viewingTimes) ->
            VideoStatistic(id, viewingTimes.sum())
        }
        .values
```

На выходе получаем:

```kotlin
[VideoStatistic(1, 5), VideoStatistic(2, 2)]
```

Comment: @IgorNovikov, если мой ответ достаточно хороший, можете за него проголосовать, нажав стрелочку вверх. Если я полностью ответил на ваш вопрос, то вы также можете отметить его зелёной галочкой.